# udev working with SYMLINK but not with NAME

Tags: udev

**Problem:**

I'm writing persistent naming rules for a USB dongle following the tutorial [here](https://www.domoticz.com/wiki/PersistentUSBDevices). The rule works as expected for :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", SYMLINK+="custom/ttyUSB-ZStick-5G"
```

This creates a symlink to the original device file `/dev/ttyACM0`.

```
$ ls -la /dev/custom/ttyUSB-ZStick-5G 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 16 12:48 /dev/custom/ttyUSB-ZStick-5G -> ../ttyACM0
```

However, I need to have `/dev/custom/ttyUSB-ZStick-5G` as a real device file not a symlink. To do that I've tried:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", NAME="custom/ttyUSB-ZStick-5G"
```

But this hasn't produced the correct result.

**Reasearch and reference**

Reading `man udev` I can't conclude if this is possible:

> The following keys can get values assigned:
>
> NAME
>
> The name to use for a network interface. The name of a device node 
>   cannot be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.

First it stats that it can be assigned but disproves that in the next sentence.

Also, I've seen [tutorials](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) claiming that it's possible:

> ```
> KERNEL=="hdb", NAME="my_spare_disk"
> ```
>
> The above rule says: match a device which was named by the kernel as
>   hdb, and instead of calling it hdb, name the device node as
>   my_spare_disk. The device node appears at /dev/my_spare_disk.

**Question:**

Is it possible to have a custom device file name (not symlink) with a udev rule?

Comment: No, the man page is pretty clear - you can only assign a network interface name e.g. `ATTR{address}=="08:00:01:de:b1:0a", NAME="eth1"`.

Comment: It's clear once you know that device nodes are completely different from network interfaces :-).  E.g. you can have an ethernet network interface `eth0` that shows up in `ifconfig` / `ip link`, and you will have no device node, no `/dev/eth0` or anything else.